# convert column values to html tags

Tags: html, r

Is there a way to convert column values to html tags? For example,  I have these columns in a dataframe.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ColA = c("1", "1,2"), ColB = c("asd", "asd,dfdsf"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

```
df
ColA   ColB 
1      asd
1,2    asd,dfdsf
```

Expected output

```
ColA   ColB                 Colc 
1      asd               <table border=1><tr><th>Ratings</th><th>Text</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>asd</td></tr><tr></tr></table
1,2    asd,dfdsf         <table border=1><tr><th>Ratings</th><th>Text</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>asd</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>dfdsf</td></tr></table>
```

The values in Colc are the values in ColA and ColB. However, I am trying to make a table from it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: check the `htmlTable` package. If you need more control, then you should consider the `htmltools` package

Comment: If you need someone to help, you could atleast include `dput(df)` to your question. We cannot tell wherther the columns are strings or lists

Comment: Hi . Just added ````dput````